# Check if URL has letters and symbols on selected link

Tags: php, preg-match

i want deny the letters and symbols Of the current page and selected url

i only want numbers

```
if(@$_GET['page'] == '$string') {

if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string))
{

die("error : page url found letters and symbols");
}
}
```

for example xxx.com/index.php?page=  <---- i only want numbers

because some people put letters and symbols
like this
xxx.com/index.php?page=ABCD
xxx.com/index.php?page=!@#$

i dont want this happen because i want protect my website from sql injection

how to deny letters and symbols from selected url :index.php?page=
؟

Comment: If you want only integer then you should put `preg_match` for digit `preg_match('/\d+/ims')`

Answer (score 1):

Always use `preg_match` function because  `is_numeric`  tests whether a value is a number. It doesn't necessarily have to be an integer though - it could a decimal number or a number in scientific notation.

```
  $pageNumber = $_GET['page'];
  if(preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{0,10}$/',$pageNumber))
    {
      echo "Page is number";
    }
  else
    {
      echo "Page is not a number";
    }
```

Also not allow more than 10 digit if you are using `$_GET` for pagignation

```
/^[1-9][0-9]{0,10}$/
```

> This would allow the string to be between 1 and 10 digits long (ie the first digit plus 0-10 further digits). Feel free to adjust the numbers in the curly braces to suit your own needs. If you want a fixed length string, then you only need to specify one number in the braces.

Comment: thanks you so much Vishnu Bhadoriya  your code is better then Ynhockey   i fixed the problem now

Answer (score 0):

`is_numeric()` will check if the parameter is a number ([Docs](http://php.net/is_numeric)). Use it like this:

```
if (!is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
    die('is not an integer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to sanitize an int value is to cast it into an int (don't show an error to the user):

```
$_GET['page'] = intval($_GET['page']);
```

But if you really need to check and really need to use regex, check against something like `[^0-9]` which represents any character that can't be part of a natural number.

Without regex you can check with `is_numeric()`.